# Atom IDE Equivalent to R Studio's Object Manager?

Tags: python, object

I've been searching everywhere for this, I basically just want to find an atom package that can list out all the objects I've created in my Python script. An example would be creating an object in R studio, and finding it in the object manager where it will display the object name, type, and values.

If there is no such thing, how do python programmers remember and keep track of this? Programming in R, I work with a ton of objects, and it would be way too tedious to write them out on a piece of paper.

Comment: By writing clean, well organized code, and not just dumping everything into the global namespace. I apologise for the snark, but really, If you plan on actually learning to code rather than simply coding to do some basic data analysis, I suggest starting to let go of the training wheels given to you by things like RStudio and forcing yourself to plan and organize ahead.

Comment: In any event, Python is highly introspectable. You can use `globals()` which returns the global namespace dictionary. Alternatively, consider the Spyder IDE, which mimics RStudios object explorer